# Sybase query performance tuning

Tags: na

select(select count(scrub_result_id)
from ac_scrub_result res
where res.scrub_id(select scrub_individual from ac_scrub_individual indv
where((t.scrub_list_id!=0 and indv.scrub_list_id=t.scrub_list_id)
or (indv.opportunity_id =t.opportunity_id))
and (res.isg_id is not null or res.key_account is not null)) as total_match
from #tempacv1 t

Comment: this query is taking long time to run I want to remove co related sub query and prepare normal query

Comment: can anyone help me quickly